# how to update a text field in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

in my wordpress blog i have a table consist of users and their products seperated by ";" for example :

```
       mytable
----------------------
userid  | products
----------------------
   1    | camera
   2    | books;keyboard;computer
   3    | mouse;printer
   4    | scanner
```

now in my script the user will add a new product so i need to check if that user has more than 3 products because in this case i will do nothing and will not add this product for him but if he has less than 3 products i need to add the new product to his products seperated by ";"  something like :

```
$userid = 3;
$newproduct = "ball"


if (pruduct field for that user has more than 2 ";" ) {

   do nothing

 }else{


$wpdb->update( 
'mytable', 
array( 'product' => concat(product, ";", $newproduct)), 
array( 'userid ' => $userid ), 
array( '%s' ), 
array( '%d' ) 
);
```

so the result in this example would be :

```
       mytable
----------------------
userid  | products
----------------------
   1    | camera
   2    | books;keyboard;computer
   3    | mouse;printer;ball
   4    | scanner
```

Comment: Read about `DB Normalization`. That's what you need now.

Comment: Storing data in this fashion goes against all proper [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) guidelines and principles. If you make that a proper association you won't have to mess around with it.

Comment: You will WASTE more of your time compensating for this bad DB design than you would actually doing anything useful. Rebuild your DB, with a properly normalized layout, and then you question becomes moot.

Comment: i just need to know how to add a text value to another value using $wpdb->update and concat    could you please help me with that ???

Comment: What if he's not in control of the database schema? Like he is operating on the database of another (poorly designed) system?

Comment: A bigger concern may be using `;` as your string delimiter. You'll have to escape that correctly or possibly run into issue when inserting this string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the data normalization arguments, **which are incredibly valid**, if for some reason you cannot correct that and must work with what exists.

Select the `products` column as a string and use the PHP `explode()` and `implode()` functions. You'd end up with something like this:

```
$current_products = explode(';', $user['products']);
// $current_products is now an array of the user's products.
if !(count($current_products) >= 3) {
    $current_products[] = $new_product;
}
$user_products = implode(';', $current_products);
// Insert $user_products into your table via UPDATE
```

The `implode` and `explode` functions convert strings to and from arrays based on given delimiters.

Comment: thank you for your answer ,  
i just need to know how to update my table using $wpdb->update and concat could you please help me with that ???

Comment: @user1921704 I am not sure you can include SQL statements in that way, as they are likely escaped. It is probably in your best interest to modify the string in the manner I described, and simply insert it like (using my variables) `$wpdb->update('my_table', array('products' => $user_products))`

Answer (score 0):

In WordPress, the right way to do this is with the `user_meta` table. With respect, your proposed way is not a good way.

You can set these values into the user_meta table with code like this.

```
$meta_key = '_my_products'; /* be sure to choose a unique key prefix */
add_user_meta( $userid, $meta_key, 'football', false );
add_user_meta( $userid, $meta_key, 'basketball', false );
```

You can get them back with code like this

```
$vals =     get_user_meta( $userid, $meta_key, false );
foreach ($vals as $value) {
     echo $i;
}
```

There are other functions for updating and deleting user_meta items. They work well. Read this. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta